# MySQL commenting

Tags: mysql, performance, datatable

Does making comments on every field when creating tables in MySQl affect performance in any way? I am working a database with more than 1000 tables and almost every field in every table has a comment on it. I was just wondering if this affects the performance of MySQL in any way?

Comment: Logically I can't see why.  It's meta data on the table definitions.  So does it affect performance in "ANY WAY"? Yes, if you're using the system tables and wanting to look at the comments.  However, if your question is strictly about performance on user added tables, I don't see how it could.  But it would definitely impact performance on queries involving system tables where the comments are stored and where comments are selected.  on a "is it good or bad" concept, I'd say overall they add more value than they cost. even if every field on all tables have a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, comments do not affect performance in any way.